# Why can you increment characters in php

Tags: php, increment

In PHP you can increment a character like this:

```
$b = 'a'++;
```

What I am wondering is from a language stand point why does that work?  Does php interpret a character just as an ASCII value so incrementing it would just make the ASCII value 1 higher which would be the next letter in the alphabet?

Comment: yep, that's the idea

Comment: You can't increment a literal `'a'` like that. It's a syntax error. And even if you assign `$a = 'a'` and then do `$b = $a++`, the value assigned to `$b` will be the pre-increment value. (I know it's kind of beside the point of the question.)

Answer (score 3):

Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's.
>
> For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91).
>
> Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

Comment: Thats a good tutorial for how to use it. What I am wondering is why does that work?  Does it have to do with the way the language was designed or is it just a feature that is added in under the hood

Comment: PHP was designed—at least in part—as a replacement for [CGI.pm](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) so it would strategically have many of the same features as Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Q: What I am wondering is from a language stand point why does that work?

A: Why is English written from left to right while Arabic right to left? That was the decision made by the people who designed the language. They might have their own reason to do so. I strongly believe that this was by design as if you do an Arithmetic addition ($a+1) it doesn't work the same way.

```
$a = 'a';

echo $a++; // output: 'a' , a is echoed and then incremented to 'b'
echo ++$a; // output: 'c' , $a is already 'b' and incremented first and then becomes 'c'

echo $a+1; // output: '1' , When in an arathamatic operation a string value is considered 0

// in short '++' seems to have been given special intrepretation with string
// which is equivalent to
echo $a = chr(ord($a)+1); // output: 'd' , the ascii value is incremented
```

Thanks for the question, I was not aware that '++' was applicable to strings.